# Why does cout in Qt differs from that in C++

Tags: qt, cout

The following snippet (mutatis mutandis or ngokuguqukayo in Zulu) works
with C++ but fails in Qt (where it produces the error message "Invalid operands to binary
expression (...)).

```
QString name = "Porky";
cout << name;
```

I have tried various alternative names but that didn't help.

Can anyone explain what the problem is with Qt?

I tried Googling but found no explanation.

I have solved the problem by overloading with QTextStream cout(stdout) but am curious as to why cout is not the same in C++ and Qt.

Comment: It's just that Qt didn't define overloads for suitable `operator<<` for ostreams and QString. You'd get an error with your own type too if you didn't define some yourself. Try `cout`ing a std::vector or std::map - you'll get an error too.

Comment: There is no `operator<<` overload that accepts a `std::ostream &` and a `QString` as arguments.  Either define your own or simply use something like `std::cout << name.toStdString()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt replies however my query isn't about overloads but why Qt accepts cout << "Porky"; but not cout << name; where name = "Porky".  That doesn't make any kind of sense but at least I now know that the problem isn't with me. I also tried defining my own overload but encountered the same error. Thank you once again.

Comment: For the record: Qt isn't a programming language but a C++ framework. The `std::cout` you use in C++ (without Qt) is the same that you use in C++ with Qt. It does not redefine `std::cout` or "bring it's own version" or whatever. Mat and G.M. are right.

Comment: In C++ cout << name; works but in Qt it fails.  Also, overloading works for operator<< in C++ but not in Qt. Why is that so if cout is identical in both cases?

Comment: Because the *types* you pass to `operator<<` are not the same. `"Porky"` is a *string literal* i.e. `char*` but `QString("Porky")` is a `QString`. There exists an overload for `char*` but not for `QString`.

Comment: My point is that the exact same thing works in C++ but not in Qt. Ergo, they are not the same. This goes for both cout << name and overloading operator<<. Both can be done without any problem in C++ (despite the type differences) but it seems that the same does not apply to Qt. Sure, there are various fixes to get around that but the difference remains.

Comment: `My point is that the exact same thing works in C++ but not in Qt` - this si wrong - Qt is c++. The problem you're facing here is that QString has no operator <<() for std::cout but std::string has.

Comment: Re. `"My point is that the exact same thing works in C++ but not in Qt."`: they are ***not*** the same thing.  Please re-read and understand the comments above.  As per the comment by @Friedrich , when you do `std::cout << "Porky"` the second parameter passed to `operator<<` is of type `const char[6]` which decays to `const char *` and results in [this overload (#2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) being invoked.  There is no appropriate overload when the second parameter is of type `QString`.

Comment: string name = "Porky"; cout << name; works in  C++ but QString name = "Porky"; cout << name; does not work in Qt. Same with the code for overloading operator<<. At least, that is my experience. If the same result applied in both cases, I would not be querying it.

Comment: Assuming `string` is `std::string` then `std::string name = "Porky"; std::cout << name;` will invoke [this overload (#1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).  Now ask yourself: when you do `QString name = "Porky"; std::cout << name;`, what `operator<<` overload do you expect to be called?

Comment: I don't have a problem with C++. It works as expected so the technical stuff you refer to is irrelevant.  My problem is with Qt. If string name = "Porky"; cout << name; works in C++ why does QString name = "Porky"; cout << name; fail in Qt? The overload issue relates to a class I created, which produced the same error in Qt although it worked perfectly in C++. I narrowed that problem down to the Porky/name issue so we can leave the overload thing for now.

Comment: Qt is a C++ library. Qt code is C++. QString is a type defined in the Qt library. `std::string` is a type defined in the standard C++ library. They are completely unrelated. The fact that one can be streamed to `std::cout` directly but the other can't is not surprising at all. Same for your own types - they'll work with cout if you design them to. They won't otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Mat. I have spent most of the day investigating / trying to understand this problem and your explanation tells me exactly what I wanted to know. However, I do find it surprising that QStrings cannot be streamed directly using cout (or printf). To me, that is a basic requirement.

Comment: Would someone care to write an answer for this? Thank you!

Comment: Mat's explanation satisfies my original query with regard to cout and also explains why attempting to create an overload operator<< for QStrings is futile. Frustratingly, these unexpected deviations from std C++ are not readily discernable from the Qt documentation. 
As far as I am concerned, my query has been satisfactorily resolved. Thanks to all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Re. `"...attempting to create an overload operator<< for QStrings is futile"`: sorry, but that's absolute nonsense!  Please read and understand the comments that were made above.  The problems you're having are due to the fact that no suitable `operator<<` overload is available that accepts a `QString` -- so just write one and use it...

```
#include <ostream>
#include <QString>

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const QString &str)
{
    return os << str.toStdString();
}
```

Comment: I tried your idea and it worked. Brilliant! Before posting my query I tried something very
similar that worked in C++ but not in Qt. As best I can remember, my various attempts were along the lines: 

void operator << (std::ostream &COUT,QString &NAME ){
    COUT << NAME;
}

Comment: Thank you Mr G.M. I would never have found your solution on my own.